# Cube-Get cannot find project file

Tags: file, ubuntu, permissions, project, transfer

Trying to use cube-get with Ubuntu to transfer files. When I run cube-get on windows however, it cannot find the project file, even though the project file is present. I have checked my directory and the files are in the correct places. I think this may be a permission issue. Is this a common issue? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Run on chrome, as some files use javascript. Wasn't working on Internet Explorer, which was set as my default browser